# Which one do you call "pepper", pimienta o pimiento?

Tags: translation

So I always thought pepper was the english equivalent of the spanish word pimienta

[image: a bowl of peppercorns]

But now I look the translation for *pimient**o*** and it also returns pepper (Google Translator)

[image: yellow, orange, red, and green bell peppers]

Do you call both pimienta and pimiento "pepper" or the translator isnt working properly?

Comment: Recommended further reading (see "pepper", "paprika", "chili"): https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16076/what-international-cooking-terms-sound-similar-but-have-different-meanings, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/784/translating-cooking-terms-between-us-uk-au-ca-nz?noredirect=1&lq=1 which also adresses *pimienta* / *pimiento*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, most English speakers do call both foods "pepper". There are few ways to distinguish them if you need to.

This is also known as **black** pepper (or red pepper, depending on the color): 
[image: Black pepper kernels]

On the left, you can see some ground pepper, while on the right there are some pepper kernels. You can refer to the small individual balls as pepper kernels or peppercorns.

---

The second kind you posted are also known as **bell** peppers, because they are shaped like bells.
[image: yellow, red, and green bell peppers]
You can distinguish these by color. (E.g. red bell pepper, green bell pepper)

---

Note that these are *also* peppers.

[image: a variety of peppers with labels]

Comment: _Pepper_ is a great example of an English word with plenty of ambiguity. (I just thought I'd pepper that in.)

Comment: @J.R And of course none of these should be confused with that eminent physician **Dr.** Pepper.

Comment: @StoneyB Or with the well-known pig.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Alas, she is not so well-known cisatlantically. But we do have the musical ensemble Salt N

Comment: It might help to add that sometimes "chili" or "chili pepper" is used to refer to some of the peppers in the bottom image, but never the black pepper or bell peppers. For instance, the Anaheim might be called "Anaheim Green Chilis". Also bell peppers and banana peppers may be called "sweet" peppers because they have little to no capsaicin and therefore are not "hot" peppers. Also it might help to show what is meant by the English word "pimento".

Comment: When you say "known as black pepper (or red pepper, depending on the color)" — just to note that, while 'red pepper' could mean 'red peppercorns', if someone says it without proper context ("go to the shops and get some red pepper"), it will likely be interpreted as 'red bell pepper'.

Comment: Native speaker here.  I've always understood the word "red pepper" to mean the red-coloured fruit in the second picture.

Answer (score 4):

In parts of the world like Australia, only the *pimienta* is called pepper. It is sometimes further described as black pepper, even when it does not need to be distinguished from white pepper or other colours of peppercorn.

*Pimiento* is called capsicum, after the genus that contains these vegetables. It is not usually called pepper in these areas, due to the ambiguity. Some varieties of capsicum that contain large amounts of capsaicin and therefore are hot, are sometimes called "chilli peppers" (though more often just "chillis"). They are typically used as spices rather than the whole form.

Comment: Which parts of the world are you talking about? "Capsicum" is very rare in the UK and also, as far as I'm aware, in the US.

Comment: @DavidRicherby South Asia I imagine. It can be pretty confusing for an American to go to an Indian restaurant and encounter *chilli* (or as we write it, *chili*) all over the menu: *chili* here is a (usually beef) stew flavored with *chili powder*: mostly cumin, oregano and various hot peppers, which usually go by their varietal names (jalapeno, chipotle, serrano, &c).

Comment: @Nij: it wasn't an objection but a request for clarification. It's interesting/important to know in which parts of the world some terms are used.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, according to the [Translating cooking terms](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/784/4590) big list on cooking.stackexchange it's capsicum in Australia.

Comment: This may vary in different parts of Australia, but in the areas I've visited, a "capsicum" is more commonly called a "paprika".  I've never encountered this outside of Australia, where in my experience it's either known as a "capsicum" or a "red pepper" (or "green pepper", "yellow pepper" or "orange pepper").